# TypeScript: Google "One Tap" Cannot find name 'googleyolo'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-oauth

Im trying to get Google one-tap working with typescript, the error I'm getting is `Cannot find name 'googleyolo'.ts(2304)`

```
<script src="https://smartlock.google.com/client"></script>
...
  useEffect(() => {
    const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    const getID = async () => {
      const credential = await googleyolo.retrieve({
//                               ^ error
        supportedAuthMethods: ["https://accounts.google.com"],
        supportedIdTokenProviders: [{ uri: "https://accounts.google.com", clientId }]
      }); 
      console.log(credential)
    }
    getID();
  }, []);
```

I can write an interface

```
  interface YoloInterface {
    retrieve: any
    cancelLastOperation: any
    hint: any
    disableAutoSignIn: any
  }
```

But I don't know how to tell TypeScript about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare googleyolo at the top of your module like this:

```js
declare var googleyolo: any; // or any way you see fit
```

Or create a declaration file.